# h2 database not started using windows service

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, h2, h2db

I am creating windows service using below command for H2 database :-

sc create mySer_H2DB binpath= "C:\Program Files\H2\bin\h2w.bat" ( tried h2.bat also)

but when i start the service from services.msc , error 1053 pops up showing message

" Windows could not start the service on local computer, Error-1053
The service did not respond to the start or control request in timely fashion"

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Infact when i run bat file from out side
it works well.

Thanks.

Comment: [Run as windows service](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#windows_service) in h2 database documentation.

Comment: I tried and it worked in windows 7 machine but when i did the same for windows server machine, even the service is started , the DB is not started, localhost:8082 doesn't worked..

Comment: If `netstat -noa` shows the port associated to the process and listening it should be the firewall or some kind of access rule. If the port is not present, then it is a problem with service start.

Comment: netstat -noa shows the associated port, by doing below entries in wrapper.conf file i am able to login via browser console.<br># Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.h2.tools.Server
wrapper.app.parameter.2=-tcp 
wrapper.app.parameter.3=-tcpAllowOthers
wrapper.app.parameter.4=-web
wrapper.app.parameter.5=-webAllowOthers
wrapper.app.parameter.6=-browser

Comment: But now there is one another issue, i cant see my TABLES which i have created when i have started DB as command line, My H2 db version is 1.4.179